# TikZ libraries 'shapes' and 'graphs' incompatible and compilations fails with "missing \endcsname"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, tikz-graphs

I need to use the TikZ libraries `graphs` and `shapes` in the same document. But they seem to be incompatible. Here is a minimal example that makes active use of the `graphs` library, but does not need the `shapes` library. Anyway, the compilation fails as soon as the `shapes` library is loaded.

This is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

% If the TikZ library 'shapes' is loaded, compilation fails
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,matrix,graphs}
%\usetikzlibrary{matrix,graphs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix { \node(foo) {foo}; \\ \node(bar) {bar}; \\ };
\graph[use existing nodes] { foo -> bar; };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted
<to be read again>
\tikz@lg1
l.17 \graph[use existing nodes] { foo -> bar; };
```

I use the package versions that are bundled with my LaTeX distribution. This is to say:

- MikTex 2.9
- pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
- tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex 2008/01/09 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
- tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex 2008/06/18 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
- tikzlibrarygraphs.code.tex 2010/10/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The version of `pgf` that you have is not the latest, could you try updating with MikTeX's Update manager?

Comment: are you manually updating TikZ since graph is added in v3.00?

Comment: @Torbjørn T: it is the most recent version that is provided my the MikTeX package manager. The package manager shows "2013-12-xy" as the built date for the various pgf/tikz packages

@percusse: No, I did not manually update TikZ. Why do you believe so? My 2.10 manual also mentions the `graphs` library and it is working (without `shapes`).

Comment: You have something wrong with your miktex. Although [MikTeX page](http://www.miktex.org/packages/pgf) shows that pgf was packed on 11/5/2011 9:43:10 PM, their [sources in CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages) (from where you download packages) shows pgf was packaged on 28/02/2014. In any case your example works for me with an updated miktex system.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be a bug in the MikTex bundle. I installed the most recent and stable version of PGF/TikZ from SourceForge following this guide: http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html and now it is working.